# Picasa3 "Shop" icon does not work since upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, google-picasa

I have 2 computers with 11.10 and 2 computers with 11.04.  Since up grading 2 computers to 11.04 the Picasa3 "Shop" icon does not work.

When clicking on the "Shop" icon to upload/order prints a window opens from which you select the vendor (Walgreens, Snapfish, Kodak, etc) to order prints.  After selecting a vendor a new "Orderprints/Login" window should open. Instead I get an error message " Failed to begin upload process. Please try again later."

Additionally in the lower right where upload progress is normally shown there is a message "Failed to download configuration file."  This happens regardless of the vendor chosen.  I have used Picasa 3.0 and 3.8 with the same results.  The problem only began when I upgraded to 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a solution to this issue. It can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-labs-picasa-for-linux/browse_thread/thread/4851af6758a0809f/44d2081cb503047a).

The key part is :

> If you've not already done so then install Wine. Now all you have to
>   do is copying the wininet.dll.so file from /usr/lib/wine/ to /opt/
>   google/picasa/3.0/wine/lib/wine/ overwriting the one that's there.
>   Picasa should now work